# php smarty not passing to browser unless logged in

Tags: php, html, smarty

I'm not the best at understanding these things with php and smarty, but this is really annoying.

On: http://www.euroworker.no/order, there is meant to be a display of the amount of tax included in the price like:

```
Tax (25%):    772,-
Totalt:      3861,-
```

But unless the user has logged in or created a new account, the tax doesn't display.

Here is the Smarty code:

```
<tr id="taxtr">

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    {foreach $cart.taxes.$currency as $tax}
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4" class="subTotalCaption2">{$tax.name_lang}:&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="amount taxAmount2">{$tax.formattedAmount}&nbsp;</td>
        {$GLOBALS.cartUpdate|@array_shift} //this enables the update button displayed in another td
        {/foreach}

    </tr>
```

I don't know about all the inner workings of this system ([Livecart](http://www.livecart.com)), but is there anything I can do or look through to make it force the calculation/display. That and does anyone know anything that could cause a non logged in user to not see some things?

There is also another thing with this system that to show the user's name with `${user.fullname}` the user must be on a page that is within the `/user` directory.. I don't understand why. This is not my problem, but thought it might be useful info..

Thanks..

Comment: Could you do a var_dump() of the $cart variable?

Comment: - first you should find the php code calling this template : this is the place where the values are set. Can you post it for further examination ?
- then I think you have some issues with your html :
2 values are outside TDs, one var is not properly closed :

    {$cart.formattedTotal.$currency} 

The trailing } is missing

Comment: Sorry, they were typos, I was copy pasting some stuff and that got left in, edited to correct.

Comment: @Vanco, I don't know what that is :P

Comment: @Rodolphe, I have no idea where the PHP code to set the values is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was some setting in the Admin area of this setting that is mysterously linked to this Tax calculation. I guess there's still some bugs to be ironed out.

Just had to click the checkbox for: `Enable shipping cost estimation in shopping cart page` and it works now.

Thanks for the suggestions.